# Owl carousel customised image preview pagination not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I am taking a look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaziev/EGrGN/light/) neat creation by Yunus Gaziev but there is one major problem with it - the pagination is removed as soon as you adjust the viewport, which seems to be caused by Owl, and I do not know why.

```
var owl;

$(document).ready(function() {
    owl = $("#owl-demo");
    owl.owlCarousel({
        navigation: false,
        slideSpeed: 300,
        paginationSpeed: 400,
        singleItem: true,
        afterInit: afterOWLinit
    });

    function afterOWLinit() {
        ...
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `owlCarousel` initialiser needed to have `afterUpdate: afterOWLinit` declared so that whenever the viewport was resized, it would fire the customised pagination script again.

I have refactored the existing code thoroughly, an example may be viewed [here](http://jsfiddle.net/defaye/7b7gmqda/) - my version can be cloned from [here](https://github.com/defaye/owl-carousel-thumbnails).

Answer (score 0):

I have tried debug the javascript but could not find the cause. I do think that this pagination is not recreating on the changes of viewport in `owl.carousel.js`

This is where it tries to recreate the pagination

- `base.updatePagination();`
- `base.checkNavigation();`

Check it out. I hope this will help you and others to find the root cause.

Comment: I only upvote if I find that it has helped me. I have not yet discovered if this has or not. Wait and see